# Code works only on one object at a time

Tags: java, oop, object, 2d-games

Im trying to build a simple game, built on the bases of RealTutsGML wave game(I assume some here knows it so it might help). Anyway, Im trying to make a "bot player" that will avoid the enemies and I believe that everything should be right, but for some reason it works only on one enemy at a time(Im adding enemies to the game every few seconds and the new enemy is the only enemy that works). The weird thing is, I created a circle around my enemy, and with that circle I detect nearby enemies, I have the following code: `if (circle.intersects(rectangle))`, the circle recieves the player position and updates all the time, and the rectangle gets the enemies position through a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
if (tempObject.getId() == ID.basicEnemy) {
rectangle = new Rectangle((int) tempObject.getX(), (int) tempObject.getY(), 16, 16); }
```

I set a print line if a collision occures, just to test and see, and whenever enemies hit the circle around the player, it prints "collision", **it works with all enemies**. but the following code that causes the player to move, only occures when the last created enemy object hits.

Thats how the whole method looks like:

```
    public void AImove() {
    for (int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        circle = new Ellipse2D.Double((int) player.getX() - 48, (int) player.getY() - 48, 130, 130);
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.basicEnemy) {
            rectangle = new Rectangle((int) tempObject.getX(), (int) tempObject.getY(), 16, 16);
        }
        if (rectangle != null && circle != null) {
            if (circle.intersects(rectangle)) {
                float diffX = rectangle.x - player.getX() - 8;
                float diffY = rectangle.y - player.getY() - 8;
                float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((rectangle.x - player.getX()) * (rectangle.x - player.getX())
                        + ((rectangle.y - player.getY()) * (rectangle.y - player.getY())));

                float newX = ((-1 / distance) * diffX * 10);
                float newY = ((-1 / distance) * diffY * 10);

                player.setVelX(newX);
                player.setVelY(newY);
            } else if (player.getX() != WIDTH / 2 - 32 && player.getY() != HEIGHT / 2 - 32) {
                float diffX = player.getX() - 368 + 10;
                float diffY = player.getY() - 268 + 10;
                float distance = (float) Math.sqrt((player.getX() - 368) * (player.getX() - 368)
                        + ((player.getY() - 268) * (player.getY() - 268)));

                player.setVelX((-1 / distance) * diffX * 5);
                player.setVelY((-1 / distance) * diffY * 5);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Just a short exlanation, newX/Y algorithm is not setting the player in a new position, it just sets the velocityX/Y, which moves the player to the oopsite direction of the collided enemy, if there is no collision, the player will try to go back to the center of the screen using the same algorithm).

I've also tested with a prints of the "supposed to be" new velX and velY, like so:

```
System.out.println((-1 / distance) * diffX * 10);
System.out.println((-1 / distance) * diffY * 10);
```

And again, it gives the right value no matter which enemy collides with the player's circle, but for some reason it just doesn't move, and works ONLY when the last created enemy object hits the circle.

Im kinda lost, as I really don't see a reason it wouldn't work, the condition occures, the code that needs to be executed works, but it just doesn't.
Sorry for the long post, I tried to be as specific and short as I can, if more code is needed please let me know, I just don't want to add too much code. Thanks for the help!

edit - https://github.com/pardovot/MyProjects/tree/master/AImove/Pong - link to the project in github, so you'll have all the needed information about it.

I assume that what Dezigo said about the last iteration replating the values is corret, does anyone has any ideas what I can do to fix that? Because overall I don't see a real reason for that to happen, as the actual code should run in each iteration, and actually work(which doesn't obviously....)

Comment: How do you move your player? You only set a new value, but you don't move it.  It looks logical that last iteration replaces previous.

Comment: The "newX/Y" should actually be called newVelX/Y, Im not setting a new position value, Im setting a new velocity, which moves the player(again, the code works with one enemy, so I see the player is moving and it works).
I don't want to add too much code, but I can show the player class code if needed, shortly, the player has x,y position, and velx/y, the velocity is added to the x,y position, causes it to move.

Comment: Anyone has any ideas please? I think I really tried almost everything I can think of..

Comment: It is necessary more information, since it is not clear how you instantiate each enemy. Please check how variables are working, since non-primitive types are just references to memory in Java. Maybe some reused variable is pointing always to last created. Food for thoughts.

Comment: @MarcosTonina I will upload the whole thing later when I will be able to, but Im using the same method I used to check for hp reduction when the player collides with the enemy, all the game objects are objects that inherits from the same gameobject class, and all the objects are stored in a linked list, so I simply iterate through all the objects. With hp reduction it works just fine with all the enemies. Any way, I'll upload all the files when I will be able to, thanks.

Comment: I agree that it's lack of information.  I don't understand how a player is moved. Just using setters setVelX, Y()? After that a renderer renders it? In this case, the last iteration replaces previous. Because it happens in the loop.

Comment: @Dezigo Here is a link to the project in github: https://github.com/pardovot/MyProjects/tree/master/AImove/Pong
don't mind the fact that the name is "Pong". That is a short version of the full game, I tried many things, so I hope there is nothing wrong in the code.

Comment: @MarcosTonina I added the project in github, you can take a look and see the whole thing.

Comment: Maybe you should check this items:

 1. You are using Runnable. Are you sure that you don't have concurrent problems? If I were you, I would try to create final rectangles in order to make them immutable and start debugging. Just to be sure.
 2. Verify which **instance** of the rectangles are being pointed by each variable, since you could have multiple different variables pointing to the same instance.

Comment: @MarcosTonina I will try both of those and will update, atm, Im pretty sure what Dezigo said is corrent, and the rectangle only applies to the last iteration, which is the last enemy object created, tho I can't really understand why, as each iteration should update the rectangle, and with the updating speed the game is running, it should just be so fast, it applies to all the objects.